# How to make Custom ArrayList<customeClass> using JsonObject values?

Tags: android, json

This is my codes :

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
JSONObject jsonOb=jsonObject.getJSONObject("LocationMatrix");
Log.e(TAG,"jsonOb :"+jsonOb.toString());
```

Then print out :

```
jsonOb :{"45":"NUMANCIA 39-41","44":"DEMESTRE 10","35":"ALIÓ 19","22":"ALFONSO X EL SABIO 8","36":"ROSARI 42","23":"PI I MARGALL 101","33":"MELCHOR DE PALAU 65","24":"ROBRENYO, ESC.A 55","34":"SARDENYA 545","25":"ROBRENYO, ESC.B 55","39":"L´ERAMPPRUNYA 41","26":"ROSSELLO 230","27":" ENRIQUE GIMENEZ 10","37":"CALATRAVA 1-7 E","28":"GRAN VIA CORTS CATALANES 489","38":"AUGUSTA 276","29":"AUTOVIA DE CASTELLDEFELS 135","43":"ROSARIO 37","30":"GANDUXER 72","42":"VALLDEMOSA  64","41":"VALLDEMOSA  62","32":"CONSELL DE CENT 97","40":"VALLDEMOSA  60","31":"SANTA AMELIA 22"}
```

How to make custom ArrayList using JsonObject values?

For Example :

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonOb.length(); i++) {
   int mId = intValue;
       String mTitle = StringValue;
       locationList.add(new Location(mId, mTitle));
    }
    Where LocationList is one kind of custome ArrayList<Location>.
    and Location is one kind of class which parameters id, title.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
JSONObject jsonOb=jsonObject.getJSONObject("LocationMatrix");
Log.e(TAG,"jsonOb :"+jsonOb.toString());
Iterator i = jsonOb.keys();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        try {
            String key = i.next().toString();
            String j = jsonOb.getString(key);
            locationList.add(new Location(Integer.parseInt(key), j));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```